# Reference Figure only shows Figurenumber

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

Im trying to reference a Figure with the desired output being "Abbildung 1" (Im using the german package). Instead im only the output 1, without the figure name.
My code:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt, DIV=12]{scrartcl}
  \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \usepackage{subfigure}
  \usepackage{graphics} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
  \usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
  \usepackage{amsmath} % nicer formulas
  \usepackage{amssymb}  % some additional symbols.
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{booktabs} % nicer tabulars
  \usepackage{subfigure} % subfigures in figures.
  \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % deutsche Referenzen, Trennung, etc.
  \usepackage[numbers,comma, sort&compress]{natbib} % bessere Zitierung.

  \begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfigure[]{\framebox[0.49\linewidth][c]{Bild1}} 
  \subfigure[]{\framebox[0.49\linewidth][c]{Bild2}}
  \caption{Eine beispielhafte Bildunterschrift.}
  \label{fig:FirstFigure}
  \end{figure}

  ~\ref{fig:FirstFigure} 

  \end{document}
```

Im placing the label correcly after my caption, but I still wont get my desired output.

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code so we can compile it. The class and relevant packages you use may be relevant. For standard classes, at least, you need to use either `fancyref` or `cleveref`. A bare `\ref` will only give the number. That is what it is meant to do.

Comment: I am using the german package \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} for references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing your preamble suggests that you are using `subfigure`, which is obsolete.

Use `subfig` or, better, `subcaption`.

For cross-references of the kind you want, use either `fancyref` with the `\fref` macro or `cleveref` with the `\cref` macro. Babel just gives strings for various bits and pieces. It doesn't change whether those bits and pieces are used or not.

`\ref{}` gives a formatted counter value or, sometimes, a combination of counter values. It does not indicate what kind of thing the counter refers to. If you want to specify that, either you write it or you use a package or class which provides that facility.

For example,

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage{babel,subcaption,cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{}{\framebox[0.49\linewidth][c]{Bild1}}
  \subcaptionbox{}{\framebox[0.49\linewidth][c]{Bild2}}
  \caption{Eine beispielhafte Bildunterschrift.}
  \label{fig:FirstFigure}
\end{figure}

\cref{fig:FirstFigure}
\end{document}
```

[image: typed cross references]

See the `cleveref` manual for details, options and customisation. `fancyref` is similar.

Switching the package to `fancyref`, with

```
\fref{fig:FirstFigure}
```

we get

[image: more typed cross references]